# regexp in tcl script

Tags: regex, tcl

I need help with tcl regexp. Suppose I have a file name as

```
abc1_vv24_0.099B_0.00h_2ru.tar.gz 
abc1_vv24_0.099B_0.00h_2ru.gz
```

1. I want to separate like below in single command for

   ```
   abc1 vv24 0.099B 0.00h 2ru tar.gz or gz
   ```
2. I need to get extensions separate in single command for both files

   ```
   tar.gz or gz
   ```

Comment: Se [Should “Give me a regex that does X” questions be closed?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285733/should-give-me-a-regex-that-does-x-questions-be-closed/285739#285739)

Answer (score 0):

For the first part you can use:

```
/[^_]+/g
```

This will allow you to split the string into substrings

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/K9yaVg/3/)

And for part 2 [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/K9yaVg/2/):

```
/(?:\.tar)?.\w+$/gm
```

It was a bit tricky since `.099B_0.00h_2ru.gz` is the actual extension

Comment: in first part instead of 2ru.tar.gz I want 2ru and .tar.gz separated for 1st file name and
2ru and .gz separated from second file.

Comment: You're not using Tcl syntax for regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

The first step is to use `split` with the splitting character set to underscore. You can then use a simple `regexp` on the final element to extract the extension:

```
set filename "abc1_vv24_0.099B_0.00h_2ru.tar.gz" 

set pieces [split $filename "_"] 
regexp {([^.]*)\.(.*)} [lindex $pieces end] -> bit ext
# Put the bit before the extension back in the list
lset pieces end $bit

puts $pieces
puts $ext
```

Remember, in Tcl you should always put regular expressions in braces. It stops unwanted syntax problems with minimum use of backslashes.